# how to make abbrev-mode work in Emacs non-text modes?

Tags: emacs

In abbrev-mode, I have an abbrev that expands `t` to `true`. In org-mode and other text modes, I can type words like `can't` and `don't` and it correctly identifies that these are single words and leaves them alone.

But in non-text modes, like jabber-mode, Emacs thinks `'` is a word delimiter and expands `don't` to `don'true`.

How do I tell Emacs' non-text modes that a `'` is not a word delimiter?